# Integration of Sauceconnect with Nightwatch/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I have configured my scripts in Nightwatch with sauce labs and I am able to execute any public IP on sauce labs. what I want now is to execute my private URL (actual test URL) on the sauce labs. Please assist on how it is to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch is just a testing framework and is not capable of running SauceConnect.

Directions to test your dev site with sauce connect follow.  If you haven't already, you can download Sauce Connect here: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Sauce+Connect+Proxy

From the terminal: 
   cd into the sauce connect folder sc-4.4.x-osx/bin 
   run the following command:

```
 ./sc -u <SAUCE_USERNAME> -k <SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY>
```

Once you see sauce connect up and running, go ahead and run your test suite.  You will now be able to access test sites behind your local firewall.

If you want to automate everything you will need to integrate with a CI program. There is a pretty good article on testing with nightwatch + travisCI + sauceConnect [here.](https://medium.com/@mikaelberg/zero-to-hero-with-end-to-end-tests-using-nightwatch-saucelabs-and-travis-e932c8deb695)